# how can i implement a contact form in watson assisstant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need to implement a contact form with fields in Watson assistant chatbot. I tried a Jason code in [www.hala.ai](http://www.hala.ai) but I can't seem to figure out how can I test it on the chatbot.
I have an account and I created a simple chatbot with buttons and links but I need to add a contact form to capture user information without slots in order to be saved.

Comment: Could you add to your question what you actually did? Have you an account for Watson Assistant on IBM Cloud? Have you configured anything?

Comment: I have an account and I created a simple chatbot with buttons and links but I need to add a contact form to capture user information without slots in order to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is too broad to make small enough to fit as answer.

The following link will explain how to create custom responses for your chatbot.

https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=tutorials-user-defined-response

On the page they have a demo widget where you can enter text into a form and have the colors change on hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom response types, here is an [example](https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=tutorials-user-defined-response)